# Error mapping types - Asp.Net API project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I have an **Asp.Net web API** project. And I'm implementing a shopping cart. So I have models that have to be converted to Dtos. So I'm using **automapper** to map `Models` to Dtos so I can transfer data but for some reason, I'm getting the following error.

The **error message** I get:

```
"Error mapping types.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nCartModel -> CartDto\r\nMoby.Services.ShoppingCart.API.Models.CartModel -> Moby.Services.ShoppingCart.API.Models.Dto.CartDto\r\n\r\nType Map configuration:\r\nCartModel -> CartDto\r\nMoby.Services.ShoppingCart.API.Models.CartModel -> Moby.Services.ShoppingCart.API.Models.Dto.CartDto\r\n\r\nDestination Member:\r\nCartDetails\r\n"
```

Automapper config class:

```cs
public class MapperConfig
{
    public static MapperConfiguration RegisterMaps()
    {
        return new MapperConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<CartModel, CartDto>().ReverseMap();
            config.CreateMap<CartHeaderModel, CartHeaderDto>().ReverseMap();
            config.CreateMap<CartDetailsModel, CartDetailsDto>().ReverseMap();
            config.CreateMap<ProductModel, ProductDto>().ReverseMap();
        });
    }
}
```

Automapper dependency injection:

```cs
var mapper = MapperConfig.RegisterMaps().CreateMapper();

builder.Services.AddSingleton(mapper);

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

CartModel:

```cs
public class CartModel
{
    public CartHeaderModel CartHeader { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CartDetailsModel> CartDetails { get; set; }
}
```

CartDto:

```cs
public class CartDto
{
    public CartHeaderDto CartHeader { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CartDetailsDto> CartDetails { get; set; }
}
```

CartDetailsModel:

```cs
public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CartHeaderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(CartHeaderId))]
    public virtual CartHeaderModel CartHeader { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ProductId))]
    public virtual ProductModel Product { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }
```

CartDetailsDto

```cs
public class CartDetailsDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CartHeaderId { get; set; }

    public virtual CartHeaderDto CartHeader { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductModel Product { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your mapping inside a class that extends `Profile` class.

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CartModel, CartDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<CartHeaderModel, CartHeaderDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<CartDetailsModel, CartDetailsDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<ProductModel, ProductDto>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Remove these lines:

```
var mapper = MapperConfig.RegisterMaps().CreateMapper();

builder.Services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

Only keep this line:

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

`AddAutoMapper` will scan the assemblies for any classes that extend `Profile` and load the mapping configuration from them. I will also register a mapper that you can inject in your services (`IMapper`).